# Passing user input as limit for python for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I am new to python and would like to set user input as the limit in a for loop. Code below:

```
    q = raw_input("Enter desired instances: ");
    for x in range(0, q)
       print "Hello"
```

Currently I am getting a syntax error. I have also tried %q and $q and those fail also.

Comment: `q` is a string and `range` expects an integer.  Also, no need to be explicit with the zero start because `range(n) == range(0, n)`.

Comment: You should usually post the error message and traceback with your question.  (Here the error message is something like `TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got str.`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
q = int(raw_input("Enter desired instances: "))
for x in range(q):
   print "Hello"
```

`raw_input()` return string,  need convert to int

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert the result to `int` since `raw_input` returns a string.

```
q = raw_input("Enter desired instances: ")
for x in range(0, int(q)):
    print "Hello"
```

And as a more pythonic approach since it's possible that user type a non digit input and in that case python will raise a `ValueError` you can use a `try-except` expression to wrap your code for handling the exception.

Comment: `int` instead of string would raise a TypeError (or something like that). Syntax error came from missing colon in `for`-statement :)